# How to connect mysql with rails 3 when Intantrails exists on another drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Instant-rails with MySQL running on a drive which I don't want to remove. I have recently installed rails 3.2.8 and ruby as 1.9.3. Please guide how to connect my application to MySQL.

- MySQL gems is installed
- Added gem to gem file
- database.yml file  is written as:

> development:
>   adapter: mysql
>   database: pretstreet
>   username: root
>   host: localhost
>   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
>   port:3306

When the application is executed the error as:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

I tried the rake command which shows me the error as:

> rake aborted!
>   (): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 12 column 1
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config

One more problem I am facing is, whenever I use "mysqladmin" related command in command prompt, it shows error and hangs my system.
Any idea why this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2 # or mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: xyz_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:
 socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```